# Unable to call .NET Core 3.x REST API that has anonymousAuthentication=false

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have two .NET core 3.1 apps: A Blazor web page server application and a REST API. Both on HTTP.
In my REST API controller I need to get the HttpContext.User.Identity.Name. 
To do this I need to set "windowsAuthentication": true and "anonymousAuthentication": false in the REST API. If I use Postman the REST API is working as intended.

My problem is that once I set anonymousAuthentication:false my web page can no longer access the REST API.
If I set anonymousAuthentication:true HttpContext.User.Identity.Name returns null but the the web page can call the REST API.

I suspect this i a Cors problem. I have this Cors code in my web project:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder =>
                        builder
                        .AllowAnyHeader()                        
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin());
            });

and
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this myself. Thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59329927/4919060

Before calling the REST API I added this.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
                AllowAutoRedirect = true
            };
            Http = new HttpClient(handler);
            Http.BaseAddress = new Uri("<API base URL>");

await Http.GetJsonAsync<....
```