# Blazor 6.0 Server no data showing in my Razor page :(

Tags: stored-procedures, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

hello every one please bear with me  im new to Blazor and i am trying to learn as i go with my first Blazor server app .

I have successfully coded a controller that works wonderfully with my sql server data base .  im acessing a stored procedure to return a list of values

```
using BIDM2.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BIDM2.Controlers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class InvalidAddressMappingController :ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly EXTSYS_ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public InvalidAddressMappingController(EXTSYS_ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<InvalidAddressMapping>>> Get()
        {

             return (await _db.GetInvalidAddressMappings.FromSqlRaw("EXEC BIDM_GetInvalidAddressMappings;").ToListAsync());
        }


    }
}
```

this works lovely for me .  when i visit the url base  /api/InvalidAddressMapping  i can see a lovely list of JSON as expected

however i am doing something wrong  in my Blazor page and i cnat see it for stareing at it    iget an unhandled exception which im going to catch  but can any one please tell me where i am going wrong  im plainly missing something pretty fundamental and right under my nose  but i cant see it for love nor money :(

my blazor page is coded as follows

```
@page "/viewinvalidaddressmappings"
@inject HttpClient http
@inject NavigationManager NavManager


<h3>ViewInvalidAddressMappings using controller </h3>

@if (invalidMappings == null){
    <text>Loading From Database ......</text>
} else if (invalidMappings.Count() ==0){
    <text>No Matchng Records Found In database</text>
} else {
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Record no</th>
                <th>Sales Org Pos</th>
                <th>Press Mgr Code</th>
                <th>Press Mgr Name</th>
                <th>Forming Rep Code</th>
                <th>Forming Rep Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var mapping in invalidMappings )
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-success">Button1</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Button2</button>
                     </td>
                    <td>@mapping.record_no</td>
                    <td>@mapping.sales_org_pos</td>
                    <td>@mapping.press_sales_mgr_code </td>
                    <td>@mapping.press_sales_mgr_Name</td>
                    <td>@mapping.forming_sales_rep_code</td>
                    <td>@mapping.forming_sales_rep_Name</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}



@code {
  List<InvalidAddressMapping> invalidMappings= new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
        invalidMappings = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<InvalidAddressMapping>>(NavManager.BaseUri + "api/InvalidAddressMapping");
     
    }

}
```

and it has to be something to do with

```
invalidMappings = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<InvalidAddressMapping>>(NavManager.BaseUri + "api/InvalidAddressMapping");
```

can any one please give me a kick in he right direction and show me what it is  im missing ???

thank you very much in advance all

if it is of any help im getting the following errors

```
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsyncCore<T>(Task<HttpResponseMessage> taskResponse, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
BIDM2.Pages.SalesOrgMapping.ViewInvalidAddressMappings.OnInitializedAsync() in ViewInvalidAddressMappings.razor
+
        invalidMappings = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<InvalidAddressMapping>>(NavManager.BaseUri + "api/InvalidAddressMapping");
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.HandleExceptionViaErrorBoundary(Exception error, ComponentState errorSourceOrNull)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<WaitForQuiescence>g__ProcessAsynchronousWork|43_0()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.WaitForQuiescence()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.CreateInitialRenderAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c__11<TResult>+<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedServerComponentAsync(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, object parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
BIDM2.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in _Host.cshtml
+
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
```

Comment: I am gonna ask the same thing than in your previous question: why are you using a controller instead of a service? Do you need it to be accessible by something else than the server itself?

Comment: However, you have the HTTP response code 401, which means you did not provide the authentication credentials while they were expected. Do you have any authentication system running on your controller?

Comment: Hi there T.Trassoudaine  thank you for getting back to me ill do my best to answer your comments as best as i can  please bear with me  im at the bottom of the learning curve with this one  and im trying to find the best path to climb up it :) i have coded a service that does work sucessfully  but am also trying to get a controller working for 2 reasons partially for learning so i can learn how to make both options work , also for pagination .  i have found some tutorials i am working through that will allow me to padgeinate and filter data   but all examples ifound  have been controller based

Comment: as far as authentication goes thats a very good point ! when the app is complete i am hoping to add windows authentication to it  so i can validate users  and also sucessfully log in to the database .  from what your telling me here  i think i need to some how pass through authentication details from the controller as part of the GetJsonAsync Method ?  actually that makes a lot of sense  thank you .  can you recomend to me  any training materials i can use to get myself up to speed understanding authentication and controllers  i def have a knowledge gap there i need to fill

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine thank you :) youve sent me on quite the voyage of discovery which is proving very usefull :)  i have a service that works very nicely for me .  i have a controller that works very nicely for me  when i  browse to the controller URI  (i can see the JSON )  but  when i try from my Razor page i get an authentication error.    soo that sent me off here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0  which was really helpfull

Comment: so fter going through all of that i think i am finally understanding :)  my service works  my controller works  but  when i try and acess teh controller from RAZOR i get the authentication error  .  this is a cross oregin thing like cors isnt it ?  ahh took me long enough to twig :) LOL i guess if i was using Blazor web asembly nd a seperate api app i wouldent be seeing this :)  cool thank you very much @T.Trassoudaine :) so i should move my focus i think  my controller works  but i shoudl look at seeign if i cna make pagination and fltering work in the service  if im using Blazor server :)

Comment: The idea is you are using Blazor server side, your controller does some database access, therefore it is not useful to go through the Internet from the server to make a request to itself. Controllers are mainly useful for external access. I still don't know why you can't request your own controller, it shouldn't be CORS since you are requesting on the same origin, right? Have you tried doing a request without browser (example Insomnia), to see if your controller is fully accessible without any authentication?

Comment: It seems that your authentication issue is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327818/blazor-getasync-request-returns-401-status-code . I suggest you read also enet comments on the answer.

Comment: thank you @T.Trassoudaine i will do  thank you so much for your help and guidance